# TableviewCell shows message when no data in table

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

[image]

I am using grouped tableview for developing a contact list using database. I have to show the message "No Contacts" on tableview when there is no contact in list. how can I do it?

Share your ideas..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

supposing that you are using an array to store all the contacts then use the following delegate

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   { 
   // You can also modify this condition according to a specific section

   if([YOUR_ARRAY count] == 0)
    {
    return 1;
    }
   else  
   return [YOUR_ARRAY count];
 }
```

Now adding data to table in following delegate

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  // Initialise your cell

 if([YOUR_ARRAY count] > 0){

  // add your array data to cells

  }

  if([YOUR_ARRAY count] == 0){

   // this means no contacts in array and therfore you have only one cell to display NO CONTACTS

   }

   return cell;

}
```

Comment: hay @naveen , it does nt shows any messgage. only plane tableview. how can I show the message? See the screenshot..

Comment: give me your email id i will send you a demo

Comment: i want demo this one... my mail id swathitps@gmail.com

Comment: @Swathi what are your requirements please mail me imneev@gmail.com and i'll send you a demo :)

Comment: @superGokuN,my email is laiqinyi@gmail.com would you send me a demo? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this one we used table headers.

If the table had elements in his data source, the table header was clear and had a 1px height.
If the data source had no elements, then the table header view was set as big as the table's frame and contained a message, an image or whatever you might need.

The functions (table view delegate methods, actually) we used were [height for header in section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForHeaderInSection%3a) and [view for header in section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForHeaderInSection%3a). We verified the data source inside the viewForHeader function

You can achieve the same effect using the table footers as well

Answer (score 0):

you can add  UILabel 
ande set the text of the label

```
label.text = @"No results ";
```

and you make a test

```
if ([contacts count] == 0)
{
     yourTableview.hidden = YES;
      yourLabel.hidden = NO;
}
else
{
      yourTableview.hidden = NO;
      yourLabel.hidden = YES;
}`
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,bt I have to show the message in tableview cell only.